# Safe way to store credentials in Chrome App

Tags: google-chrome-app

I'm currently working on an FTP client as a packaged Chrome App.

Is safe to store user credentials for different FTP servers using `chrome.storage.*`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store a password as securely in Chrome Extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090255/how-to-store-a-password-as-securely-in-chrome-extension)

Answer (score 0):

[According to the docs:](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage#using-sync)

> Confidential user information should not be stored! The storage area isn't encrypted.

Don't store sensitive information using the `chrome.storage.*` APIs. [See this question for more information.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265348/storage-of-passwords-in-google-chrome-extension)