# How can I pass information from Background.js to autofill.js in my Google Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, passwords

I made a Google Chrome extension that autofills and submits the username/password for certain websites (Gmail & Yahoo for now) when the icon is pressed. As of now, my passwords and usernames are hard coded on the autofill file. Now I am trying to have the passwords/usernames stored on a txt (json) file that the background page will be able to properly read that txt file(TheList) and turn the contents of that file into a string, which I can easily call the variables that I need. Now All I need to do is find a way where I can call those values from background onto autofill so that my values of the username/password can be stored onto TheList only instead of having it hard coded in Autofill. Is there anyway I could do this? Thanks for taking the time to read this

Here is my code to the following files:

**Background.js**

http://pastebin.com/XiCGXUAx

**Autofill.js**

http://pastebin.com/C0TiF9yB

**TheList.json**

```
{
"GmailUsername": "USERNAME1",
"GmailPassword": "PASSWORD1",
"YahooUsername": "USERNAME2",
"YahooPassword": "PASSWORD2"
}
```

Sorry I had to post all of my code through the links but that was because it kept saying that my code wasn't indented correctly but all of the code I had posted was in the grey box.
Thanks for taking the time, I really need to find a way so I could have the usernames/passwords be read off the TheList and then look into ways where I can encrypt that list after.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you can use [Messaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

---

Consider the following idea: you set up a listener in your `background.js` and then inject your content script:

```
// background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(passwordRequest);

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(
    function (tab) {
        // ...
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "autofill.js"});
    }
);
```

Then, your content script initializes and reports the domain of that tab to the background page:

```
// autofill.js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({domain: location.hostname}, fillPassword);
```

Back in the background page, you handle that message:

```
// background.js
// Option 1: you have synchronous functions to get username/password
function passwordRequest(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    var username = getUsername(request.domain);
    var password = getPassword(request.domain, username);
    if(password !== undefined) {
       sendResponse({username: username, password: password});
    } else {
       sendResponse({error: "No password found for " + request.domain});
    }
}

// Option 2: your storage API is asynchronous
function passwordRequest(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    getCredentials(                   // Your async credentials retrieval
        function(username, password){ // Callback
            if(password !== undefined) {
               sendResponse({username: username, password: password});
            } else {
               sendResponse({error: "No password found for " + request.domain});
            }          
        }
    );
    return true; // Required for asynchronous sendResponse
}
```

Back in the content script you handle the response in a callback:

```
// autofill.js
function fillPassword(response){
    if(response.error){
        console.warn(response.error);
        alert(response.error);
    } else {
        // autofill with response.username and response.password
        // ...
    }
}
```

For added bonus, you can store domain-specific id's for form fields and pass them along with the credentials.

*Note: I have not tested the above code.*

---

On a related note, instead of fetching a local file with XHR, **you should consider other available options for storing local data**, especially if you want to write to it. A good overview is [here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_storage).

---

Another important thing to take note of is security. **There is no secure/bulletproof way to store sensitive data in a Chrome extension.** See those discussions: [Password storing in Google Chrome content scripts](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35688/password-storing-in-google-chrome-content-scripts), [How to store a password as securely in Chrome Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090255/how-to-store-a-password-as-securely-in-chrome-extension)