# Security Concerns of Entirely Localized Password Manager

Tags: javascript, security, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm creating a Chrome extension to autofill username and password for one specific site, "example.com". I would like to make EVERYTHING localized to prevent any security concerns. My process is as follows:

- on Options page, user can input username/password, which is saved in `chrome.storage.local`
- on "example.com", the extension autofills the username and password with `chrome.storage.local.get(() => ...)`

What are the security concerns of this?

**What I've Considered** 

I'm concerned about

1. Chrome says `storage.local` is not safe, but they do not provide reasons. Liability?
2. Chrome also says `storage.local` is unique per chrome extension / site. So the ONLY way for an attacker to steal a password is by hacking me and / or my source code, and pushing malicious changes to my extension, correct? (if there's any other way it's a definite no-go)
3. Ideally, I would have the password / username be encrypted, with e.g. AES-256. But if everything's local, there's either one master key (which any attacker could find) or a unique key that's stored "securely somewhere" in the app, maybe created at install. << but where to store that? If there's a "secure somewhere" in the app, I should just put the password / username there.

I'd like to do this without a server, however if that's not possible I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Related SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090255/how-to-store-a-password-as-securely-in-chrome-extension

Comment: You can create an application on your computer for password storage and then make a local connection between the extension and the application for sharing the passwords. It would give you more storage opportunities.